# No such property: INTEGER for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

A query is composed as follows:

```
def subQuery = {
    ge("date", fromDate)
}

def query = {
    projections {
        sqlProjection 'sum(hoursBefore+hoursAfter) as totalHours', 'totalHours', INTEGER
    }
    and subQuery
}
```

and then executed as follows:

```
def results = WorkLog.createCriteria().get(query)
```

I get the error:

> No such property: INTEGER for class:
>   grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried java.lang.Integer?

Comment: Forget that. Invalid comment. It should work with INTEGER.
=============================================================================
Have you tried WorkLog.withCriteria directly?

Comment: Try something like:
=============================================================================
  def results = WorkLog.withCriteria {
   projections {
    Projections.sqlProjection(
     'sum(hoursBefore+hoursAfter) as totalHours', ["totalHours"].toArray(new String[1]), [Hibernate.INTEGER].toArray(new org.hibernate.type.Type[1])
     )
   }
   and subQuery
  }

Comment: Try to omit `projections{}`, I had a similar issue with `sqlProjection`, and try to write explicitly the full package name grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.INTEGER (or org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER in some grails versions)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as in a new project I setup to try this. For some odd reason couldn't fix the error with that approach. It could be a Hibernate version issue or grails does not support that syntax.

Here's a workaround that worked in the test:

```
def results = WorkLog.createCriteria().list {
        projections {
            addProjectionToList(Projections.sqlProjection(
                'sum(hours_before+hours_after) as totalHours', ["totalHours"].toArray(new String[1]), [Hibernate.INTEGER].toArray(new org.hibernate.type.Type[1])
                ),'sum')
        }
        and subQuery
    }
```